# StageText not dispatching keyboard events

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem with my StageText field not dispatching the keyboard events. StageText is implemented on an AS3 only project. Everything works fine except that when I hit the return key, nothing happens...

below follows my code:

```
_input                      = new StageText(new StageTextInitOptions(true));
_input.text                 = _trackerData.trackerComment;
_input.maxChars             = Globals.TRACKER_INPUT_CHARS;
_input.fontFamily           = "Antenna Regular"; 
_input.softKeyboardType     = SoftKeyboardType.DEFAULT;
_input.returnKeyLabel       = ReturnKeyLabel.DONE;
_input.autoCorrect          = true;
_input.fontSize             = ScreenUtils.cmToPt(.25);
_input.color                = 0x000000;
_input.fontWeight           = "normal";
_input.stage                = this.stage;
_input.viewPort             = new Rectangle(    ScreenUtils.cmToPx(.35), 
                                                ScreenUtils.cmToPx(1.5), 
                                                stage.stageWidth - ScreenUtils.cmToPx(.7), 
                                                ScreenUtils.cmToPx(3)
                                            );
_input.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpEventHandler);

private function keyUpEventHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace("keyCode", evt.keyCode);
}
```

But the function is never getting called!
Anybody knows what the problem may be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine with a text field created on the stage in Flash itself, might have something to do with all of the parameters you set beforehand. Comment some out in a few different tests to see which is affecting the listener?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find why, but if you use the ReturnKeyLabel.DONE, it don't work! Try with another, like ReturnKeyLabel.GO

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event listener BEFORE setting the viewport property

Comment: oh well, thanks for the tip! I went for another solution, it´s a long time now...